# Using href in Javascript with webpages like google

Tags: javascript, window.location

This is gonna sound like a dumb question or maybe it is a dumb question and I apologise in advance, but I am having a problem trying to get my window.location.href to show an alert on webpages like google and youtube.

It shows alerts on the live server fine, however its just that I can't tell if its working on webpages like google and youtube as I am not seeing any alerts. When I do run it, I do see it re opening the tab I just minimised, so it maybe working, but is there any other form of validation too see if it is working.

I'm still pretty new to JavaScript but this is the code I'm using, any advice would be much appreciated. Thank you again

```
<p id="URLc"></p>
  <script>
    document.getElementById("URLc").innerHTML =location.href
    alert('This website is'+ window.location.href);


  </script>
```

Comment: Is this question about issues with Google crawling your site?

Comment: not really I don't think? I just want to see if it works and if it alerts me what the current URL name is, so that I can move onto regex the URL and filtering out certain symbols, so the alert, is just for validation to make sure it work. If that all makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

I see that your question isn't clear enough.

However, if you want to navigate to another web page from yours and display an alert there. You can not display alerts in web-pages which you don't owe because the page you open will have a separate script and your JavaScript code won't affect it.

- You can display the alert before changing the `location.href`.
- You can use `postMessage()` as illustrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29306621/javascript-open-link-in-new-page-and-run-script).
- You can display a pop-up window with the message you want to display, by making another `HTML` file, adding the message you want to it, and doing like this:

```js
window.open( {{THE HTML FILE URL}} , 'popup', 'width=600,height=600');
window.location.href = {{THE URL YOU WANNA NAVIGATE TO}};
```

*Not That you're able to pass the URL you want to navigate to to your HTML file using [Query Strings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string)*

If your question is about displaying your `location.href` on your website, it should just work fine. I opened `https://www.youtube.com/?feature=ytca`, opened the browser console and ran `alert(window.location.href);` and the alert got displayed.

If you don't mean this, please make your question more clear.

Comment: Oh okay thank you again for the explanation, yeh all I wanted to do was to check if it works. My main goal is to validate the URL address through the use of regex, to filter out certain symbols etc, as I am creating a detection program that filters out certain webpages (not for my website more of a algorithm). the alert was only to see if it work. Thank you