# How can I open a link in Chrome from Photoshop to download an image?

Tags: javascript, photoshop

I'm creating a script in Photoshop using JavaScript that I want to open chrome for all types of windows users and open a link in chrome. After the chrome is open and link is insert I want to complete a form with values that I know and submit the form, the new link that is generated I want to open and download the image.

Using my code the error I received on Photoshop is "the window is undefined", but if I delete `window.open` line the chrome open using the script in Photoshop.

Here is my code. Any solutions?

```
var commandtoRun = "C:\\PROGRA~1\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe"; 
app.system(commandtoRun,"","","open","1");
var windowObjectReference;

window.open( 
    "https://www.yourURL.com", "_blank");
```

I did it with

```
window.onload = function() {
    window.open("https://www.w3schools.com");
}
//openRequestedPopup();

//file.remove();  
var site="//mylinkwithform"; //your side

      if (  $.os.indexOf("Windows") != -1 ) 

      {//SYSTEM IS ONE OF THE WINDOWS
                          app.system("cmd.exe /c\"start http://"+site+"\"" );
                }
                          else{//MUST BE MAC
                          system.callSystem("open http://"+site);
          }
```

How i insert the values in the form from the site and submit the form?

Comment: The photoshop JavaScript does not have a window object.
You should try putting the url as a parameter in the list for the app.system call.

Comment: I did it with the code from above. Now I need to now how I insert elements in form and use the next link that is generated.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29306621/javascript-open-link-in-new-page-and-run-script pls investigate this page.